# How to order firebase realtime data same as it is stored in firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I have tried everything but data is not coming in order , even snapshot is showing data in unordered form

I'm developing chat app. i want to maintain the order of the data so chat must show in order, but its not happening. whenever i send message it placed between the old messages not in the bottom

Here the latest message "what are you doing?"

[image]

here's the chat. look where is that latest message "what are you doing?"

[image]

my code for observing messages

```
public func getAllMessagesForConversation(with id: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Message], Error>) -> Void) {
  
    database.child("\(id)").queryOrdered(byChild: "date").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String:Dictionary<String, Any>] else{
            completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
            return
        }

        var messages = [Message]()
        for i in value {
            
            guard let message = i.value["message"] as? String else {return}
            
            let senderId = i.value["sender"] as? String
            let recieverId = i.value["reciever"] as? String
            let messageID = i.value["id"] as? String
            var DATE = Date()
            if let date = i.value["date"] as? String {
                DATE = ChatViewController.dateFormatter.date(from: date)!
            }
            var kind: MessageKind?
            
            kind = .text(message)
                
                let finalKind = kind
                
                let sender = Sender(photoURL: "",
                                    senderId: senderId!,
                                    displayName: Api.Params.inputUserName)
                
                let abc = Message(sender: sender,
                            messageId: messageID ?? "",
                            sentDate: DATE,
                            kind: finalKind!)
                
                messages.append(abc)

            if messages.count == value.count {
            messages = messages.sorted(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
                lhs.sentDate.toMillis() > rhs.sentDate.toMillis()
            })
            }
            print(messages)
        }

        completion(.success(messages))
    }
}
```

Comment: When you call `snapshot.value` the keys and values are returns as a dictionary, which means it loses information about ordering. To retain this information, you need to loop over `snapshot.children` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166483/firebase-getting-data-in-order/40168370#40168370

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you did not include key "date" to be indexed in firebase.

Go to firebase console database, go to Rules tab, enter and save:

```
"emantrasports":{
   "$conversationID": {
     ".indexOn": ["date"]
   }
}
```

[image]

There is a different approach to order your data on client side.

Firstly you need to create a model of your Message, that contains all necessary variables and also a date variable. And then order your array of message objects by your date variable.

Comment: Thanks bro for the response , In Firebase rules , i have read and write options , where should i add this code ? Under which body ?

Comment: @HanzalaRaza I updated my answer with image. Check it out.

Comment: ok understood , one thing i need to ask how can i reference that childbyautoID ? how did you find that $conversationID could be used in place of childbyautoID ?

Comment: @HanzalaRaza You can get child auto id by accessing key value. In your case it's - i.key

Comment: awesome , thanks alot , could you help me regarding messageKit ? whenever i comes on the chat screen my msgs always comes outside the viewController (Behind Navigation bar) , I always need to scroll down for correct alignment .... Check the edit

Comment: @HanzalaRaza Sorry, I don't know usage of Message Kit. As an idea - you can set collection view top inset to something like - 16 or 24. collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 16, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)